# "Http failure during parsing" for my service

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, jhipster

I try to code my first service in a JHipster application. So I have a component whith this call

```
this.saisonsService.getActiveSaison().subscribe((resultat: HttpResponse<ISaisons>) => {
        const existSaison = resultat.body;
        //TO DO
        }
      }, error => {
        // TO DO
      });
```

And th service with

```
  getActiveSaison(): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http.get<ISaisons>(`${this.resourceUrlActiveSaison}`, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

In the Backend, the service is OK :

```
    @GetMapping("/saisonActive")
public ResponseEntity<Saisons> getActiveSaison() {
    log.debug("REST request to get active Saison");
    Optional<Saisons> saisonActive =  saisonsService.getActiveSaison();
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(saisonActive);
}
```

But when I call it, i have this error

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "http://localhost:9000/api/activeSaison",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:9000/api/activeSaison",
    "error": {
        "error": {},
        "text": "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"fr\" dir=\"ltr\">\r\n  <head>\r\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" />\r\n    <title>pdf4pweb</title>\r\n    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"Description for pdf4pweb\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"google\" content=\"notranslate\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\" />\r\n    <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#000000\" />\r\n    <base href=\"/\" />\r\n    <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" />\r\n    <link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"manifest.webapp\" />\r\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"content/css/loading.css\" />\r\n    <!-- jhipster-needle-add-resources-to-root - JHipster will add new resources here -->\r\n  </head>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <!--[if lt IE 9]>\r\n      <p class=\"browserupgrade\">\r\n        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href=\"http://browsehappy.com/\">upgrade your browser</a> to improve\r\n        your experience.\r\n      </p>\r\n    <![endif]-->\r\n    <jhi-main>\r\n      <div class=\"app-loading\">\r\n        <div class=\"lds-pacman\">\r\n          <div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n          </div>\r\n          <div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n            <div></div>\r\n          </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n      </div>\r\n      <div class=\"app-loading\">\r\n        <div id=\"jhipster-error\" style=\"display: none\">\r\n          <!-- This content is for troubleshooting purpose and will be removed when app renders -->\r\n          <h1>An error has occurred :-(</h1>\r\n          <h2>Usual error causes</h2>\r\n          <ol>\r\n            <li>\r\n              You started the application from an IDE and you didn't run <code style=\"color: red\">npm start</code> or\r\n              <code style=\"color: red\">npm run webapp:build</code>.\r\n            </li>\r\n            <li>\r\n              You had a network error while running <code style=\"color: red\">npm install</code>. If you are behind a corporate proxy, it is\r\n              likely that this error was caused by your proxy. Have a look at the JHipster error logs, you will probably have the cause of\r\n              the error.\r\n            </li>\r\n            <li>\r\n              You installed a Node.js version that doesn't work with JHipster: please use an LTS (long-term support) version, as it's the\r\n              only version we support.\r\n            </li>\r\n          </ol>\r\n          <h2>Building the client side code again</h2>\r\n          <p>If you want to go fast, run <code style=\"color: red\">./mvnw</code> to build and run everything.</p>\r\n          <p>If you want to have more control, so you can debug your issue more easily, you should follow the following steps:</p>\r\n          <ol>\r\n            <li>Install npm dependencies with the command <code style=\"color: red\">npm install</code></li>\r\n            <li>\r\n              Build the client with the command <code style=\"color: red\">npm run webapp:build</code> or\r\n              <code style=\"color: red\">npm start</code>\r\n            </li>\r\n            <li>Start the server with <code style=\"color: red\">./mvnw</code> or using your IDE</li>\r\n          </ol>\r\n\r\n          <h2>Getting more help</h2>\r\n\r\n          <h3>If you have a question on how to use JHipster</h3>\r\n          <p>\r\n            Go to Stack Overflow with the\r\n            <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jhipster\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">\"jhipster\"</a> tag.\r\n          </p>\r\n\r\n          <h3>If you have a bug or a feature request</h3>\r\n          <p>\r\n            First read our\r\n            <a href=\"https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\"\r\n              >contributing guidelines</a\r\n            >.\r\n          </p>\r\n          <p>\r\n            Then, fill a ticket on our\r\n            <a href=\"https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new/choose\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\"\r\n              >bug tracker</a\r\n            >, we'll be happy to resolve your issue!\r\n          </p>\r\n\r\n          <h3>If you want to chat with contributors and other users</h3>\r\n          <p>\r\n            Join our chat room on\r\n            <a href=\"https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">Gitter.im</a>. Please note\r\n            that this is a public chat room, and that we expect you to respect other people and write in a correct English language!\r\n          </p>\r\n          <!-- end of troubleshooting content -->\r\n        </div>\r\n      </div>\r\n    </jhi-main>\r\n    <noscript>\r\n      <h1>You must enable JavaScript to view this page.</h1>\r\n    </noscript>\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n      // show an error message if the app loading takes more than 4 sec\r\n      window.onload = function () {\r\n        setTimeout(showError, 4000);\r\n      };\r\n      function showError() {\r\n        var errorElm = document.getElementById('jhipster-error');\r\n        if (errorElm && errorElm.style) {\r\n          errorElm.style.display = 'block';\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    </script>\r\n    <!-- Google Analytics: uncomment and change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID.\r\n    <script>\r\n      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=\r\n      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;\r\n      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];\r\n      e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';\r\n      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));\r\n      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');\r\n    </script>-->\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this code don't work ... Have you an Idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you receive JSON? It seems to me that you receive HTML (see the "text" property"), have you inspected the response in Chrome dev tools? I suppose that this is for Angular?

Comment: Sure it's Angular with JHipster. The problem is that I don't send anything (no parameters) and the http request is never send to the back (I think that the creation of the request failed). But I don't know why it's text and not JSON

Comment: Have you checked that your request headers include the correct mime-type? From what you say, it's not clear to me that you inspected request/response in network tab of browser's dev tools. Could you do it and paste req/resp in your question? If the request was not sent to backend you would not receive html.

Comment: I don't know why but a clean/restant has resolve this issue ..